# Group dialog items to a single "Group" (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, dialog

I want to create a dialog window for change settings of an application. Below is a screenshot of Adobe Reader. After using Spy++, I guess that:

*On the right side, all the control (buttons, combo boxes...ect) are belonged to a GroupBox.*

*For each category in the TreeView Control on the left side, there is a corresponding GroupBox which groups all the controls related to this category.*

*When users choose between different categories, it hides one GroupBox and shows another one GroupBox.*

But in the source code (xxx.rc, resource file) below, I didn't see anywhere where I can specify the "parent" of a dialog item.

Even I open xxx.rc with "Resource View" (not viewed as codes), I can't find any option to specify the parent of a dialog item in its property page.

I would like to know how to assign a parent (which is a GroupBox in my case) to a dialog item, or group dialog items to a single group,in the .rc file, i.e when one create the dialog items. (I guess one can do so by modifying the .rc file.)

```
GROUPBOX        "View",IDC_SECTION_VIEW,101,6,228,88
LTEXT           "Default &Layout:",IDC_DEFAULT_LAYOUT_LABEL,107,19,108,9
COMBOBOX        IDC_DEFAULT_LAYOUT,215,17,108,64,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | WS_TABSTOP
LTEXT           "Default &Zoom:",IDC_DEFAULT_ZOOM_LABEL,107,36,108,9
COMBOBOX        IDC_DEFAULT_ZOOM,215,34,108,149,CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_TABSTOP
CONTROL         "Show the &bookmarks sidebar when available",IDC_DEFAULT_SHOW_TOC,
                "Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,107,53,216,9
...
...
...
```

[image]

Comment: Group boxes do not group controls. They are merely a visual aid to convey the dialog designer's intention. It is the `WS_GROUP` window style that controls arrow key navigation, and `WS_TABSTOP` for [Tab] key navigation. Since your assumptions are wrong so is your solution based on that assumption. In fact I still don't understand what you really want to do. It would help if you described your ultimate goal without explaining your proposed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know how to assign a parent...

[`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API. You supply `HWND` of your control and the handle of the supposed new parent.

In resource script, the controls will be children of the dialog itself, but on runtime you are free to change this and group them into a hierarchy of your interest.

You might also want to consider putting the supposed child groups into separate dialog template and have it as "composite control" - to be instantiated separately and be a child of a higher level dialog.

UPD. Have a look at this simple project (C++/ATL): [AtlChildDialog](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/AtlChildDialog). In particular, [at main dialog's WM_INITIDIALOG handler](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/AtlChildDialog/MainDlg.h#L44):

```
ATLVERIFY(m_ChildDialog.Create(m_hWnd, (LPARAM) this));
ATLVERIFY(m_ChildDialog.MoveWindow(50, 50, 200, 150));
m_ChildDialog.m_EditWindow.SetWindowText(_T("Some Text"));
m_ChildDialog.ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
m_ChildDialog.SetFocus();
```

[image: IDD_MAIN]

[image: IDD_CHILD]

All together on runtime:

[image: Run Time]

Comment: Yes, I know this solution. But this does the work not in the .rc file, but in another .cpp file. I just wonder if one can do this when one create the dialog items in .rc file. I edit my question to specify this point, but thanks.

Comment: OK, thank you let me know one cannot specify a dialog item's parent in .rc file.

Comment: `.RC` control's parent will be the dialog box, you don't have the flexibility to override this. You can re-parent controls on runtime, and you can design separate templates and "merge" them on runtime into hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks. By "...putting the supposed child groups into separate dialog template", do you mean that: Create 2 dialog windows, and on runtime, set one as a child of another one?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make the child one borderless and seamlessly fitting the master dialog.

Comment: @ Roman I got a question now. After creating 2 dialogs, say D1 and D2, using DialogBoxParam, I didn't figure out how to set D1 as a child of D2. The problem is : the return value type is INT_PTR, and also DialogBoxParam doesn't provide a parameter for setting the parent windows (only for setting owner window). So I have to use SetParent function in WM_INITDIALOG message of D1_Proc (to set D1 as child of D2). But in D1_Proc, I don't have the handle of D2, since the handle of D2 is visible in D2_Proc. Do you have an idea how to do this, without introducing global variables.