# Is there a way to parent a standard Windows dialog inside another form?

Tags: windows, winapi

I know it's possible to take [a dialog that you built yourself and parent it on another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031580/group-dialog-items-to-a-single-group-visual-studio/14031634#14031634).  But is it possible to parent a standard Windows system dialog on a form that you designed?

Specifically, I'm trying to set up a form with multiple tabs that provide different ways to obtain a reference to data used by the program.  One of those tabs should represent the file system, and the ideal way to do this would be with [the standard Open dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that can be instantiated with the COM identifier `CLSID_FileOpenDialog`.

Is there any way to take a system dialog and cause it to appear parented on another window, without the border, title bar, etc?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to use a hook, either via `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()`, to grab a system dialog's HWND, then you can do whatever you want with it, such as call `SetParent()`.  But just because you CAN does not mean you SHOULD.  System dialogs are designed to run as their own windows, not embedded in someone else's window.  A better solution might be to use the same Shell display components that are used by Windows Explorer (and system dialogs) via `IShellFolder::CreateViewObject()` or `SHCreateShellFolderView()`, or find a third-party solution that does the hard work of interacting with the Shell for you.

Comment: I've considered that.  But the problem with building my own shell view is that, even if I build one that looks exactly like current Windows dialog box, it probably won't look like a current dialog box when the next version of Windows comes out.  An OS dialog will.

Comment: This is tricky because you are trying to take a modal dialog (with its own message loop) and make it modeless so that it uses the app message loop. So somehow (with a hook or some sort) you have to get access to the dialog after it has been created but before it enters its model loop. Just looking at the MFC CDialog::DoModal() will give you an idea of the complexity involved. Not for the faint-hearted!